# $request is uninitialized in AuthenticatesUsers.php Laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, request, sendmail

I want to send a notification email each time logging in successfully(just for testing since I'm out of email for registration to test sending email). I modify the handleUserWasAuthenticated function which I assume that this function will be called when logging in successfully. However, I cannot take email and username from the form's data through $request variable. The $request is also used in other places in handleUserWasAuthenticated function by default and there's no warning for these cases while only in my added codes, $request get warning "Variable $request seems to be uninitialized". How can I take the email and username for sending email?

This is the handleUserWasUathenticated function in AuthenticatesUser.php

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
    {
        //My modification
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Welcome to Myfirstsite',
            'content' => 'You have finished your registration successfully'
        ];

        Mail::send('emails.verification', $data, function($message){

            $message
                ->to($request['email'],$request['name'])
                ->subject('Verification email from Myfirstsite');

        });

        //Original part
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this code : `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

not `use App\Http\Requests\Request;`

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` is in `AuthenticatesUser.php` by default.